# Responsive font-size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

hi i'm new to webdev and i was tring to make my first full-responsive webpage
but i had a problem that the text is extra large for the mobile version
so i did set the width to #vw as i though that will fix it
but it didn't go as i wanted as the text get alot smaller being unreadable + the page looks ugly with it
can you guys help me please?

> ``
>
> ```
> .#### {
> font-size: 2.5vw;
> font-weight: 700;
> text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
> }
> ```
>
> ``
> and i expected it to make the font size change with the width and it did but alittle bit over what i wanted and now with the mobile version the text is unreadable

Comment: Various things may help, a text shadow on a small font is inclined to make it look blobby for example and you would need to force the size to not go below something readable. Can you give us more code see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Often narrow viewports will require a different layout, not just decreasing text size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries.
Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.
It uses the `@media` rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

So here you can use a condition that if device is mobile then use these css (i.e. css for smaller font)

```css
#para {
  font-size: 40px;
}

// This CSS will run for mobile devices
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  #para {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="para">
  arches to delightful measures. Grim-visaged war hath smooth'd his wrinkled front; And now, instead of mounting barded steeds To fright the souls of fearful adversaries, He capers nimbly in a lady's chamber To the lascivious pleasing of a lute. But I,
  that am not shaped for sportive tricks, Nor made to court an amorous looking-glass; I, that am rudely stamp'd, and want love's majesty To strut before a wanton ambling nymph; I, that am rudely stamp'd, and want love's majesty To strut before a wanton
  ambling nymph; I, that am not shaped for sportive tricks, Nor made to court an amorous looking-glass; I, that am curtail'd of this fair proportion, of the ocean buried. Now are our brows bound with victorious wreaths; Our bruised arms hung up for monuments;
  Our stern alarums changed to merry meetings, Our dreadful marches to delightful measures. Grim-visaged war hath smooth'd his wrinkled front; And now, instead of mounting barded steeds To fright the souls of fearful adversarie
</p>
```

You can even add breakpoints for multiple screen widths,
like say for `device width >1000px` use font `20px` ,then from `width 500` to `1000px` use font `15px`, then for `width <500px` use font `10px`, etc, anything you may like.

**Also I am providing you some breakpoints which I use, you can search for better maybe:**

```css
@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px)  { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```